# Owin server in UWP

Tags: .net, win-universal-app, owin, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

lets say I have a asp.net core mvc app witch use the entity framework core and I want have mobile app for these project.

Is there some way, tutorial, example. How to host asp mvc core app in UWP app? I mean something like Phonegap, but thanks on C# code on server so much stronger. My idea is have owin server in UWP and connect to this server from webview so server and client will be in same application.

Answer (score 0):

The UWP sandboxing and the available libraries prevent this currently. IMHO, kestrel's libuv dependency, functionality from a higher version of the .NET Standard Library than which is currently available in UWP and the .NET Native compilation process would block that.

See the following ticket: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1338. It contains a answer from a Program Manager for ASP.NET.